# LCD doesnt display as desired with Arduino

Tags: arduino, lcd

I have a problem working with the LCD and Arduino.

When i use the example code for LiquidCrystal.h that displays HelloWorld the LCD works perfect. But when I add the same as part of another code, the LCD doesnt display well. it just flickers a few letters and then gradually fades away.

Basically I want to display the data that I get from a computer's browser that is connected to the same network that the Ethernet Shield is connected to. But I am just trying display the basic one so that I can edit accordingly.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

boolean incoming = 0;

byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDA, 0x02 };
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,117); 

EthernetServer server(80);

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("hello, world!");

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("My IP Address is: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop()
{

  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(millis() / 1000);

  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {

    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();

        if(incoming && c == ' '){ 
          incoming = 0;
        }

        if(incoming == 1){
          Serial.println(c);
        }

        if(c == '$'){ 
          incoming = 1; 
        }



        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } 
        else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }

    delay(1);
    client.stop();
  }
}
```

The example code that works is:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a conflict between the pins used for the LCD and the pins used for the Ethernet shield.

If you're using an Uno, the [Ethernet shield uses the SPI bus](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet) on pins 11, 12, and 13.  This line from your code:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
```

says that you're also [using pins 11 and 12 for the LCD](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalConstructor).

You probably need to use different pins for the display or use a different board like an Arduino Mega, which gives you more choices for the SPI bus.

Answer (score -1):

Which LCD and ethernet hardware are you using? For example, if you use LCD-Display on top of Arduino ethernet-shield, there is a hardware conflict and you actually have to do some modification (in my case, cut pin 10 from the LCD). Pls let us know your hardware setup.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment on the question rather than as an answer.

Comment: I am using a separate LCD and connected it to the Ethernet Shield pins that is fit above the Arduino. Problem solved. It ws the conflict of pins.